# When someone is pointing angrily to your face (rudeness)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Let's say someone has got something to say about you to your face. As you know, in many cultures, it is rude to refer to someone with the forefinger (especially when it comes to anger or an argument!) Now, let's imagine you're from such a culture and a person is referring to you with their index fingers in a very angry way!
How would you warn them?
I have made up some sentences and I wonder which one sounds natural to you to be said to such a situation?
If none of them works here, then I would appreciate it if you let me know about the most natural way to say that.

> 1. Don't **point at me.**
> 2. Don't **point to me.**
> 3. Don't **point at me with your finger.**
> 4. Don't **point to me with your finger.**

Comment: It's not uncommon in North America to hear, "Get your finger out of my face!" However, this is also pretty rude and this is a sentence that escalates tension, rather than diffusing it.

Comment: Just the first one: "Don't point at me". They will know you mean **finger** because that is what is being pointed.

Comment: You've asked a lot of rather intriguing questions. Out of curiosity, are you writing a novel? Have you been involved in all of these situations you ask about? Or do you just think of random scenarios to improve your English? (Please don't take this as criticism! Just curious!)

Comment: "Don't wag your finger at me!" would be pretty common in the UK when someone was to move the index finger up and down and up, as to threaten or reprimand someone

Comment: "Don't point your finger at me" is the common reply. The sensibility to "the finger" is a North American thing. Brits do not have this sensibility to "the finger" as we use two fingers not one. A Hang over from the Archers in the 100 years war.

Comment: So @Brad, do you mean that Americans tend to say: "don't point **your finger** at me," while Britons say it removing "**your finger**". If so, these two mean the same and there is just a regional nuance. Do you confirm?

Comment: To me (British), there is no practical difference between "don't pont at me" and "don't point your finger at me". The latter might be a bit more emphatic.

Comment: In confrontational situations it is usual to say "Don't point (your finger) **at** me". "Point **to**" is more usual when you are indicating someone or something. "I'm pointing **to** the way out"

Comment: @Brad I think you are confusing the OPs question with rude/obscene gestures. This question is about pointing the index finger aggressively towards someone, not pointing the middle finger upwards from a clenched fist (giving the bird) or gesturing with two fingers, (the V sign).

Comment: I agree with Colin Fine & Peter Jennings , I actually said the opposite of what A-friend has commented and regarding rude gestures I was commenting on, the  first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointing a finger *at* someone may indeed be rude.  Pointing a finger *to* someone is usually not rude at all.

The reason is that these imply different contexts.  Pointing *at* someone is an aggressive gesture often indicating *accusation*.

> The prosecutor **pointed at** the defendant as she addressed the jury.  "Ladies and gentleman," she exclaimed, "the state will show that *this* is the man who committed the vile murder on the night of October 7th!"

Pointing *to* often merely indicates *selection*.

> The two captains had the boys line up along the goal line.  Each then took turns **pointing to** one of the boys to call him over onto his team.

This use can subtly change the nuance of an implied action:

> "Mrs. Capshaw, can you show us the man you saw entering your neighbor's house the night of the murder?" the prosecutor asked.
>
> Mrs. Capshaw nodded and pointed **to** the defendant. (selection)
>   Mrs. Capshaw nodded and pointed **at** the defendant. (accusation)

As for the answer to your question, it mostly depends on how aggressive you want to phrase your response.  A simple request might be:

> (Please) Don't point your finger at me.

or, alternately, you can take Canadian Yankee's suggestion of

> Get your finger out of my face!

with a range of possible options in-between.

Answer (score 1):

The original post's suggestions are grammatically correct.  Their literal meaning is also semantically correct.  The "at me" examples are more consistent with the intended meaning than the "to me" examples, but the "to me" examples are accurate enough.

But none of the original post's examples convey the original poster's intent.

The original poster's intent is to convey, "In my culture, pointing at someone's face is incredibly rude.  Let's have a polite conversation without any pointing at faces."

If the original poster is conversing with someone who is not aware of this point of etiquette, the purpose of the original poster's statement will be completely lost.  Instead, the other person will hear that someone whom they are already angry with has dared to issue them a command!  And is trying to change the subject!  And is prohibiting them from expressing their anger!  Maybe the other person will obey, and stop pointing their finger at the original poster's face.  But even if they do, they will be even angrier, and the overall effect will be counter-productive.